# UITableView Custom Trailing Action Button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I've have been able to execute the standard action button (i.e. delete) through a `uitableview` utilizing the `delegate` method `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`.

My issue is basically trying to replace the action button with a custom button, for example, that has padding between the cell and the action button, has rounded edges, and is inset within the cell.

Haven't been able to find any leads and any thoughts would be appreciated..

Below is the desired goal:
[image]

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, view, completion) in
        print("Delete Pressed")
        completion(true)
    }

    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    delete.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "trash")

    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false

    return config
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.subviews.forEach { subview in
        if (String(describing: type(of: subview)) == "UISwipeActionPullView") {
            if (String(describing: type(of: subview.subviews[0])) == "UISwipeActionStandardButton") {
                if let actionButtonCGRect = actionButtonCGRect {
                    subview.subviews[0].bounds = actionButtonCGRect
                } else {
                    actionButtonCGRect = subview.subviews[0].frame.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 10)
                    subview.subviews[0].bounds = actionButtonCGRect!
                }

                subview.subviews[0].layer.cornerRadius = 10
                subview.subviews[0].clipsToBounds = true
                subview.subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can checkout this https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit or a number of other options here https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#table-view--collection-view

Comment: @Chris, Go for a trivial custom cell solution/pod. Here is another tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2436-how-to-make-a-swipeable-table-view-cell-with-actions-without-going-nuts-with-scroll-views